# How terminal decides which program to open when multiple binaries of same name on path?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have multiple binaries of the same name in various directories listed in the `PATH` variable.

I have multiple binaries because I use different versions of the same software for different things.

I have some trouble when the wrong version opens at the wrong time, and would like to learn how it is determined which exact binary is opened (as opposed to the others of the same name, also on PATH) ?

Comment: The first found in $PATH is the one used.  You can control your executed binary using the order of entries in $PATH.

Comment: See also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#File-location_related_variables

Comment: Nitpicking: the terminal doesn't decide it. The shell decides it, the terminal prints whatever it is given to print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first found in $PATH is the one used.

You can control your executed binary using the order of entries in $PATH.